# Microwave Popcorn...Possible Mouse/Rat feces?

Tags: food-safety

Maybe this is more of a health question, but I was eating some microwave popcorn and bit into a piece that just tasted absolutely terrible. Rest of the bag tasted like normal and wasn't overly burnt or anything.

Anyways it hit me that....holy crap I might've eaten rat feces. Is this something I should be worried about? I mean I imagine a bag of popcorn gets pretty hot inside...so wouldn't it eradicate most bacteria/etc...

Comment: Why would you make the leap from "popcorn" to "rat feces?"  Was there some other evidence?  Lot's of things have the potential to taste terrible, but, as pointed out below, mw popcorn contains only a few ingredients, and is sealed.

Comment: True but the corn obviously is pumped into the bags. Not sure why I went to rat poop, it was just REALLY gross tasting.

Comment: Probably just a bad kernel that did not pass quality control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microwave popcorn bags operate on being sealed and trapping the heat inside in order to get the temperatures you need to pop the popcorn. If a rat had defecated in your bag he would have broken the seal to do it. No you didn't eat rat poop.

Rather you likely ate a singly rancid popcorn kernel which tasted pretty crummy. This is not altogether uncommon and therefore the far more likely explanation.

Comment: You obviously never looked into a factory or a corn silo, otherwise you would know that rats are a very real concern. Hint: *Corn does not grow in sealed bags!*

Comment: Yeah, probably a rancid kernel....but still hopefully that doesn't make me sick (Haven't gotten sick yet at least). And yeah I mean I imagine the rat pooping in the corn that goes into the bag of course ha!

Comment: @Mercfh It won't make you sick. and the prospect of the feces getting into the bag before it was sealed is certainly possible but it is way less likely than aa bad kernel. After all the factory can probably prevent any noticeable amount of feces with a quick rinse just before bagging.

Comment: @bruglesco I guess is there any reason a bad kernel would make me sick? Im assuming the heat in the bag would probably kill most bacteria

Comment: @Mercfh No reason to think it might make you sick.